APIM + WebAPI Cannot Import OpenAPI/Swagger API
setup: APIM + WebApi are in the same VNET, differnet subnets, with NSG rules
I am able to create an API manually in APIM and call the WebApi endpoint without any issues.
I am not able to import OpenAPI definition directly when entering the Swagger path to the OpenAPI import dialog.
Could it be so certain inbound/outbound rules for the import from the browser need to be added on NSG level?
Any ideas how it works?


have you tried to download the file and then import it?

yes, downloading json and then importing it as file works, but then I need to specify the URL manually after that.

You can specify the backend URL using policy too. I believe If you will try to import it using the URL then it won't work as your URL is not publicly accessible. You can only import those URLs which are publicly accessible

The URL call comes from an IP address, so if I knew which IP it is, I could whitelist it. However, I have not figured out how to find it.
